# How do I run Google Web Toolkit applications from the command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

At the moment I'm running the demo StockWatcher in Eclipse.  This uses the embedded servlet container which is fine for my purposes.  The only change I would like to make is running from the command line instead of inside Eclipse.  Does anyone know what command I use and what classpath this requires?

Edit - I have not used maven I have created the project purely using eclipse and gwt plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used the webAppCreator wizard (I see that you used the Eclipse plugin, but maybe both of them used the same code internally), you should have an ant script (`build.xml`) generated for you. With it you can run the GWT app via targets so:

- `ant hosted` - run hosted mode (or Development mode, I'm looking at a fairly old ant script)
- `ant gwtc` - compile to JS
- `ant war`, `ant build`, etc.

See what's in that file (`build.xml`) to get a better understanding of what is available and what you can do.

**Update:** see [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefCommandLineTools.html#webAppCreator) for documentation on webAppCreator and available ant targets.

Answer (score 0):

With the maven jetty plugin you can run your application with jetty from command line. (You first have to compile & create war with maven gwt plugin I think)

```
mvn jetty:run
```

[maven gwt plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/)

[maven jetty plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Maven for this project? If that, then you can run it as `mvn gwt:run` from command line